# TinyMCE is glitchy/unusable in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, tinymce

I'm using the jQuery version of TinyMCE 3.3.9.3

In firefox, it works fine (10 sec video depicting it in use): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrAE0igfT3I

In IE8 (in IE8 standards mode), I can't type or click any buttons. However, if I use ctrl+v to paste, then I can start typing, but the buttons still don't work (a 45 sec video depicting it in use): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBSRlE8D8F4

The jQuery TinyMCE demo on TinyMCE's site works for me in IE8.

Here's the init code:

```
$().ready(function(){

    function tinymce_focus(){
        $('.defaultSkin table.mceLayout').css({'border-color' : '#6478D7'});
        $('.defaultSkin table.mceLayout tr.mceFirst td').css({'border-top-color' : '#6478D7'});
        $('.defaultSkin table.mceLayout tr.mceLast td').css({'border-bottom-color' : '#6478D7'});
    }

    function tinymce_blur(){
        $('.defaultSkin table.mceLayout').css({'border-color' : '#93a6e1'});
        $('.defaultSkin table.mceLayout tr.mceFirst td').css({'border-top-color' : '#93a6e1'});
        $('.defaultSkin table.mceLayout tr.mceLast td').css({'border-bottom-color' : '#93a6e1'});
    }


    $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
        script_url : 'JS/tinymce/tiny_mce.js',
        theme : "advanced",
        mode : "exact",
        invalid_elements : "b,i,iframe,font,input,textarea,select,button,form,fieldset,legend,script,noscript,object,embed,table,img,a,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6",

        //theme options 
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,selectall,|,undo,redo,|,cleanup,removeformat,|", 
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "bold,italic,underline,|,bullist,numlist,|,forecolor,backcolor,|", 
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "", 
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "", 
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top", 
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left", 
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "none", 
        theme_advanced_resizing : false,

        //plugins
        plugins : "inlinepopups,paste",
        dialog_type : "modal",
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,

        setup: function(ed){
            ed.onInit.add(function(ed){

                //check for addEventListener -- primarily supported by firefox only
                var edDoc = ed.getDoc();
                if ("addEventListener" in edDoc){
                    edDoc.addEventListener("focus", function(){
                        tinymce_focus();
                    }, false);

                    edDoc.addEventListener("blur", function(){
                        tinymce_blur();
                    }, false);
                }

            });
        }

    });


});
```

Any ideas as to why it's not working in IE8?

[edit]: stripping everything out of the init (leaving just script_url and theme) results in the same symptoms

Comment: +1 for adding the video links, it certainly illustrates the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I visited this code, so I went through it again after updating to tinymce 3.4.4.

As it turns out, a parent fieldset element had both position:relative and z-index:-1 applied. Removing the z-index property then allowed tinymce to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no tinymce instance without adding control to a specific html element.
Eigther you set mode from "exact" to "textareas" or you will have to addControl to an element using `tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',true, element_id);*`

Comment: Isn't that just another way of just initializing tinymce?

Comment: indeed, but from your question i asume that the initialization takes place under IE8? do you get any js errors at all?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a # in your URL while the Editor is initialized. Strange but I got a few problems because of it.  Making sure there is no # in URL did solve a couple of problems similar to this. Hope it works out with you.

Comment: Nope, there is no # in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

may be it would be too late
i met same problem. in ie9 & ie7 everything ok, but in ie8 can't type or click any buttons

on page was "noscrpipt" tag with inline-styles (i know, there is bug with ie8 and background style in noscript btw)

and solution was - remove inline-style in noscript tag (or tag itself), and tinymce began working perfectly

Comment: It wasn't the issue in this case, unfortunately.